# drupal commerce separate shipping for different products

Tags: commerce

We have a drupalcommerce website through which we sale

- iptv box
- qwerty key board

on adding first product it adds 15 dollars( base rate ) + 5 dollars per item in cart, so if we have 1 item in cart the shipping is 20 dollar but if we have 2 products the shipping will be 25 dollars and so on.

problem is, we want to setup separate shipping rate for qwerty key board if there is only a qwerty key board alone in cart the shipping must be 5 dollars.

I hope this can be done through shipping rules

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you ever figure out how to calculate different shipping rates based on line item product type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a shipping service dedicated for for qwerty key board and similar items and a shipping calculation that checks for a certain product in the cart. Use:
Event: Calculating a shipping rate
Condition: order contain a particular product. 
Action:Add a rate for a shipping service to an order and select the shipping service that is dedicated for qwerty key board and similar items.

It may be easier for you to clone one of the existing shipping rate calculation and edit as needed.

Comment: if order contains product A it adds 10 dollars to all items in the cart and if order contains product B, it adds another dollar 5 per product in shipping

Comment: Try this method: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/videos/demo/using-calculation-rules-add-peritem-shipping-commerce-shipping it utilizes a flat rate shipping for the base rate and calculation rules to add any amount to every item. You may need to have one calculation rule for every product type (+$5 and +$10). You will also have to provide a calculation for what happen if both products are in the cart.

Comment: I have already seen that video, in-fact that is what I used to configure shipping rule which adds a dollar 5 to the base rate for each item added in the cart. But there is no clue to setup separate shipping rate for different product types.

Comment: Is there a way we can loop action to line items of specific product types or sku.

Comment: I would create a separate rule for each sku and run a loop through the line items(commerce-line-item:order:commerce-line-items) is condition is true.

Comment: That's what I have told you, If order contains product A it ads dollar 5 to all items in the cart, similarly when 2nd condition is also true like if order contains product B it runs over the loop again and adds the specified amount again to all products in the cart

Comment: "if order contains product A it adds 10 dollars to all items in the cart"

There are three options:

 - Cart contains product A
 - Cart contains product B
 - Cart contains products A & B

Rules by itself does not provide a way to create conditional rules but there is a module for that [link]http://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional

If you rather not use the above module you'll need three rules that check for each of the above scenarios. You can manage these rules in a component of type "Rule Set" where they will be evaluated one after the other.

Comment: I have achieved my desired result by combination of 3 shipping rules. #1 if order contains product a and product b #2 if order contains product a and not product b (negate option was checked) # if order contain product b and not contain product a (Also added negative amount out of loop )

Answer (score 0):

This video shows how to set up seperate shipping costs per line item  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3zQ3OMxUdQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! On this site it is generally considered bad habit to post link-only answers. Have a look at the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about writing good answers. Please add some additional details that make your answer independant of the linked video.

Comment: That video isn't available any longer. Can you please post steps or an updated link?